How to add controller endpoint in swagger in ApiPlatform (Symfony)?
I use ApiPlatform and want to have few endpoints in controllers.
How can I make these endpoints visible for swagger and how can I give swagger docs informations (eg. description)?

I tried to add #[ApiResource] attribute, but it's not work for controller.
I also added adnotation, but it isn't working too:

    /**
     * @Route("/my-endpoint", name="my_endpoint", methods={"GET"})
     * @OA\Get(
     *     path="/my-endpoint",
     *     summary="This is my custom endpoint",
     *     @OA\Response(
     *         response=200,
     *         description="Successful response",
     *         @OA\JsonContent(
     *             type="object",
     *             @OA\Property(
     *                 property="message",
     *                 type="string",
     *                 example="Hello, world!"
     *             )
     *         )
     *     )
     * )
     */


I wanted to point controller from entity like this:

#[ApiResource(
    operations: [
        new Post(
            uriTemplate: '/user/register',
            controller: RegisterController::class
        ),
    ]
)]

and it's give me visible endpoint in documentation, but I can't use that solution in my case

The last point in the Documentation is what you need.
https://api-platform.com/docs/core/controllers/
"Alternatively, you can also use a traditional Symfony controller and YAML or XML route declarations. The following example does the same thing as the previous example"
<?php
    // api/src/Controller/BookController.php
    namespace App\Controller;
    
    use App\Entity\Book;
    use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Attribute\AsController;
    
    #[AsController]
    class BookController extends AbstractController
    {
        public function createPublication(Book $book, BookPublishingHandler $bookPublishingHandler): Book
        {
            return $bookPublishingHandler->handle($book);
        }
    }

and add the symfony classic to the routes:
# api/config/routes.yaml
book_post_publication:
    path: /books/{id}/publication
    methods: ['POST']
    defaults:
        _controller: App\Controller\BookController::createPublication
        _api_resource_class: App\Entity\Book
        _api_operation_name: post_publication

